# Calculate average of population data read from a text file

Tags: java

I wrote a program that processes population data from 1950 till 1990. I'm trying to get the average from a text file. Everything in the program compiles but I'm getting 0 for the output. Why isn't this working?

Here is the Java program I wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class PopulationData
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    final int SIZE = 42;
    int[] number = new int[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int average;

    File file = new File("USPopulation.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (inputFile.hasNext() && i < number.length)
    {
       number[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
       i++;
       total += number[i];
    }

    average = total / number.length;

    System.out.println("The average annual change in population is: " + average);

    inputFile.close();
  }
}
```

USPopulation.txt:

```
151868 153982 156393 158956 161884 165069 168088 171187 174149 177135 179979 182992 185771 188483 191141 193526 195576 197457 199399 201385 203984 206827 209284 211357 213342 215465 217563 219760 222095 224567 227225 229466 231664 233792 235825 237924 240133 242289 244499 246819 249623
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the USPopulation.txt file

Comment: You increment `i` before adding `number[i]` to your total, so you are skipping the first value. Also I don't know if you're simply doing this since you're required to, but the array isn't needed for you to do this.

Comment: 151868
153982
156393
158956
161884
165069
168088
171187
174149
177135
179979
182992
185771
188483
191141
193526
195576
197457
199399
201385
203984
206827
209284
211357
213342
215465
217563
219760
222095
224567
227225
229466
231664
233792
235825
237924
240133
242289
244499
246819
249623

Comment: that is whats in the text file sorry

Comment: **Population Data Java** strange question tittle which is not related to piece the question body code.

Answer (score 3):

Change this :

```
 number[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
 i++;
 total += number[i];
```

to this :

```
 number[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
 total += number[i];
 i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the average from a text file everything in the
>   program complies but I'm getting 0 for the output.

You are doing integer division. Make `average` and `total` double instead of int.

Comment: @LKTN.25 found the fix

Comment: That only results in always rounding down the result by truncating to an integer, but it's not the cause of getting zero as the result.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, when I posted my answer, the OP had not given the other details that that he has give now.